# How can I prevent WiFi router owner from seeing what websites I visit?

Tags: wifi, surveillance

Like when using public wifi, what can I install/use on both my Android phone and Windows laptop to make it impossible (or very difficult for someone who is not an expert) from seeing what websites i visit?

Answer (score 0):

You can route your connection through a VPN.  This will encrypt the connection from your device to the VPN provider, therefore making it impossible for the wifi router owner to scan your traffic.  See [Understanding VPNs : How VPNs can be used for anonymization?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/understanding-vpns-how-vpns-can-be-used-for-anonymization?rq=1) for more info.

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend using a VPN (Virtual Private Network), and of course, it should be switched on immediately after connecting to the WiFi access point. A VPN would encrypt your network connection, so that even a skilled network admin would find it nearly impossible to see your traffic.

Comment: Unfortunately, after technical corrections, this now looks exactly like the other answer.