# Receiving phishing text messages

Tags: phishing, phone, sms

I get a phishing messages on SMS every now and then. I'm not sure if it's from anyone that knows me.

What information can I get about the sender of the SMS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does IP tracking work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15134/how-does-ip-tracking-work)

Comment: @vidarlo I think Elic is asking how to get the IP address from the text in order to analyze it.

Comment: Not much, normally Spam SMS are from spoofed phone numbers etc