# how to trace a hacker

Tags: anonymity

How to trace a hacker how knows what he is doing.He covered all and what now? 
I em interested how hackers stay anonymous and don t get caught and what are the techniques used by forensic investigators to catch them.

Comment: This really isn't a good fit for this site - you should have a look at http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2231/why-is-it-difficult-to-catch-anonymous-or-lulzsec-groups?rq=1 though, which covers most of the relevant points, and @TomLeek has the rest of them sorted :-)

Answer (score 4):

People involved in morally dubious activities get caught because they are live in a physical world in which they breath, drink, eat, leave fingerprints and are visible to surveillance cameras.

Harry Potter performs most of his mischievous shenanigans under the cover of his invisibility cape, and yet Dumbledore always finds out what he did.